# ipad tabbar rotation

Tags: ipad, rotation, tabbar

please help with this noob questions but really making me go crazy>

if I create a project from scratch (using windows based app) for the ipad,
and add a tabbar , with firstviewController, and secondviewController, it works fine, 
starts in landscape mode,
but in info.plist I set it to Landscape(left home button),
but really in simulator starts with the button on the right side!

in the FirstViewController.m

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
  interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
  return YES;
  else {
  return NO;  }}

so it starts in landscape, and rotates as the simulator rotates,

but if I create a template app for iphone tabbar,
set the info.plist
Initial interface orientation> Landscape (left home button)

and add the code above, IT DOESNT WORK!!!
simulator starts with button at left but tab bar on the side,

same problem that I had with an app that Im porting from iphone to ipad, (landscape intended)
I get to the landscape start mode, but the tab bar remains on the side!

also the only way to make the old ported app to show the simulator on the side was with
UIInterfaceOrientation UIIntefaceOrientationLandscapeLeft (didnt work with Initial interface orientation), does not let me choose the value for the key, but it shows the simulator on landscape,,

so,, 
what can I do please to show the tab bar on landscape mode???
the tabbar from scratch was made to see if the code will work , but it didnt??
why does it work in the tab bar made from windows app and not tab bar app?
I just want the tab bar to show in landscape ahhh,

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the info.plist set Supported Interface Orientations